# Google Analytics API: Creating arbitrary "dimensions" to group metrics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a requirement to programmatically get unique visitors grouped by partial matches on some fields. For example, assume I want to group my users by the source domain like "google" or "facebook".

A single user's visits might come in with a `ga:source` of "m.facebook.com" and then "www.facebook.com" on another visit, or "m.google.com" and "www.google.co.uk", etc. I can perform an API query specifying "ga:source" as the dimension, and it will give me the unique visitors for "m.facebook.com", "www.facebook.com", "m.google.com" and "www.google.co.uk" respectively. However users who visited via more than one of them in the requested period are counted in each group, so aggregating this data subsequently into "facebook" and "google" groups results in duplicate users being counted.

Would it be possible to group the "ga:source" dimension using a Regex (`^(?:.*?\.)(.*?)(?:\..*)` for instance) or some similar arbitrary mechanism so that I can get two groups of unique visitors instead: "facebook" and "google"?

I can of course, use filters to get each category and then perform multiple requests and that works fine, but being the lazy programmer I am, I was wondering if I could do it all in one go, or if anyone had alternative suggestions I haven't thought of.

Comment: In which bucket do you want users to be counted that have visits both via facebook and google ? Your question is difficult to answer because ga:source is a session-scope dimension and users are, well, user-scope.

Comment: Yes, it's a bit of a pickle. In this case, I would expect them to be re-counted per group - so once for Facebook and then again for Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conclusion appears to be that the only way is indeed to submit a filtered query for each desired grouping of unique users. So I shall do that. :)